# generalized cross product with proving the perpendicularilty

Tags: abstract-algebra, determinant

I understand this is how we define the generalized vector product for higher dimensions. That is for $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ linearly independent, write $w$ vector with component $w_i=det(v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_i)$ with $e_i$ being the standard unit vector. But I have trouble showing $w\cdot v_i=0$ for all $i$. I tried to use the Lebnitz expansion, let $A_i=(v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_i)$ I have $$w\cdot v_i=\sum_{l=1}^nv_{il}w_l=\sum_{i=1}^nv_{il}\cdot\text{det}(v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_i)
$$
$$=\sum_{l=1}^nv_{il}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^nA_{k\sigma(k)}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^nA_{k\sigma(k)}\cdot \sum_{l=1}^nv_{il}=0$$

Next I wish to show there exists an index $k$ for any $\sigma\in S_n$ s.t. $A_{k\sigma(k)}=0$. Anyone have a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A hint as requested:

Since the determinant as a function of $n$ vectors is linear in each operand,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n v_{il} \cdot \det(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}, e_i) =
\det\! \left(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}, \sum_{i=1}^n v_{il} e_i \right) $$